# What does "as" mean?

Tags: meaning

> ...If we bet on the existence of God and win, then we gain eternal
> life. However, if we choose to bet on the option that God doesn’t
> exist, and we win, then we live a life without illusion (at least in
> this respect), and feel free to indulge in the pleasures of this life
> without fear of divine punishment. But if we bet on this option and
> lose, then we at least miss the chance of eternal life, and may even
> run the risk of eternal damnation. Pascal argued that, **as** gamblers
> faced with these options, the most rational course of action for us is
> to believe that God does exist. <sub>[Source](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Pascal%20argued%20that%2C%20as%20gamblers%20faced%20with%20these%20options%22)</sub>

What does "as" mean in the context? I think it means "like". Is it correct?

Comment: As means: like gamblers, yes. This is probably en tant que in French....

Comment: @Lambie I don't think it's exactly "like" - "like gamblers" implies you're not a gambler, "as gamblers" implies that you *are*, which I'm pretty sure is Pascal's intended meaning here.

Comment: This is translated from the French. Pascal said belief was a gamble. So, I guess the as is since: since we are gamblers faced with this choice. It would be great to see the French original.

Comment: @Lambie  I disagree with your first comment - 'as' here means "since we are all".  He is not making a simile, but stating a fact: we are all gamblers.

Comment: 'Pascal's Wager' is his suggestion that  it is worth betting on the existence of God, since there is everything to gain if He does exist and not much to lose if He does not. You could say "From the point of view of gamblers..."

Comment: There is really no statement of fact: it is either a simile or a since clause and without the original French, there is no way to **tell** exactly.

Comment: It's irrelevant exactly what Pascal wrote in the original French. As @MaciejStachowski says, ***as*** in the cited text definitely means ***since** [we **are** "gamblers"]*, not that we are ***like*** gamblers.

Comment: @Lambie - I don't think there is an "original French" here. This is not a translation of Pascal's writings, this is an author named Nigel Warburton describing Pascal's Wager in his own words and in English.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Pascal wrote only in French. Of course, there is a French text. There are the texts by Pascal where he describes all this.

Comment: @Lambie - Of course Pascal has described this in French, but that does not mean that the English clause "as gamblers faced with these options" in the OP's text was directly translated from any of Pascal's French writing.  That phrase was composed by the British author of the textbook in order to express Pascal's ideas.

Comment: https://www.franceculture.fr/philosophie/le-pari-de-pascal-croire-en-dieu-sur-un-coup-de-des des joeurs, thus: it means: Since we are gamblers. I never said that it was translated from the French. I SAID one has to see how Pascal TALKS about it IN French, to get it. Thus, those texts will show if this is merely a metaphor or not. It turns out it is not a metaphor. It is a mathematical calculation, as it were.

Comment: http://www.ifac.univ-nantes.fr/IMG/pdf/10-_Pascal_Pense_es_fragment_sur_le_pari.pdf parier = to bet .

Answer (score 1):

There's a distinction between *as* and *like* - *like* is used to equate the subject's characteristics with something, while *as* is used to denote that the subject *is* that something. Compare the following two sentences:

> As a tiger, Mittens had bright orange fur.

> Like a tiger, Mittens had bright orange fur.

The first sentence clearly indicates Mittens *is* a tiger, and posits that tigers generally have bright orange fur. The second one, on the other hand, indicates that Mittens is *not* a tiger - he might be a regular house cat - he's just similar to a tiger with regard to his fur.

The distinction in your sentence is more subtle, but it's there. The author wants us to think that we're not merely *behaving like* gamblers, but we *are* all gamblers faced with Pascal's wager. A better way to rephrase the sentence would be:

> Pascal argued that we are gamblers faced with those options, and that the most rational course of action for us is to believe that God does exist.

Answer (score 0):

You might expand

> as gamblers faced with these options

to read

> reasoning as gamblers do when considering a bet with some
> chance  for an infinitely valuable win - their gambler's mathematics tells them to
> bet -

Comment: I don't think this is right. You're saying ***as*** in the cited context means ***in the same way as*** (i.e. - we're not ***actually*** "gamblers"; we're just ***like*** them). But I think the intended sense is ***as = because, since*** (because ***we really are*** the gamblers being referred to).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That wording would be OK with me too. Add a parenthesitical "because we are the gamblers in this situation". We are each expanding a little French into a lot of English.

Comment: We're only really concerned here with the meaning of the *English* text - so I don't think it makes any difference what Pascal thought or wrote. For me, the killer argument is *...faced with **these** options*. If we assume ***as = like*** that doesn't make sense, because such "generic" gamblers wouldn't be facing these specific options (except insofar as gamblers are human beings, so they're included in ***us*** as mentioned later). If it truly was a "simile", it would have to be *...faced with **such** options* (options ***like*** the ones ***we*** are facing, not the actual same ones).